# Return the sorted array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

Imagine i get two arrays as input, one of which is already sorted. I want to create a method which checks which array that is sorted and then returns it. Im not really sure how to do this

```
class Program
{
    public double[] a = new double[] { 1, 3, 4, 8, 21, 38 };
    public double[] b = new double[] { 1, 7, 19, 3, 2, 24 };

    public void CheckSorting()
    {
        if (/* if a is sorted */)
        {
            return a; 
        }
        else { /* This should be OK because if A isnt sorted then b MUST be sorted since of the arrays are always sorted in my input */
            return b;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program checkSorting = new Program();
        checkSorting.CheckSorting();
    }
}
```

In this case, as you can see the array A should be returned as the sorted one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just.... loop over one of the arrays in a forwards direction; if the value ever goes down, that array isn't sorted

```
for(int i = 1 ; i < a.Length ; i++)
{
    if(a[i] < a[i-1]) return b;
}
return a;
```

Comment: Only works for arrays sorted in ascending order. Granted, OP hasn't indicated that the arrays may be sorted in any other fashion.

Comment: @Scott indeed, but trivial to extend the concept

Comment: @MarcGravell Im getting an error that says:
Since 'Program.CheckSorting()' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Comment: You need to change the function declaration to  public double[] CheckSorting()

Answer (score 0):

```
private double[] ArraySort()
        {
            double[] a = new double[] { 1, 3, 4, 8, 21, 38 };
            double[] b = new double[] { 1, 7, 19, 3, 2, 24 };

            var isOrderedAscending = a.SequenceEqual(a.OrderBy(x => x));
            if (isOrderedAscending)
                return a;
            else
                return b;
        }
```

this method might help you,
but what has to be achieved if both or not ordered ?